# Nodejs+ cradle, scoope of variable on callback

Tags: node.js, couchdb, cradle

I'm wondering if you can help me with my problem. my Code is :

```
test = function (_mappedReq, _callback, _req, _res, _session){
    _mappedReq.created_at = new Date();
     nbConnSaveCallback =0;
      connectDB().database("users").save(_mappedReq, function (err, res) {
              nbConnSaveCallback +=1;
              logger.debug("nbConnSaveCallback="+ nbConnSaveCallback);
              if(err){
                logger.minor("Error while trying to save " + s.doc._id, lambda);
                   _callback(err, null);
              }else{
                  logger.debug("Succeed to save);
                  console.log("res._id = " + res._id );

                 _callback(null, res);
}});
}


connectDB = connectDB = function(){
  if(_.isEmpty(this.dbConnexion)){
    logger.info('Opening connexion to couchDB');
    this.dbConnexion = new cradle.Connection(this.config.db.url, this.config.db.port, {
      auth: { username: this.config.db.username, password: this.config.db.password },
      cache:false
    });
  }
  return this.dbConnexion
}
```

When I go in high frequency calling test function some time the result of nbConnSaveCallback is > 1 ?

Do you have any idea of what can append ?

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer to my question i must put 'var' in front of nbConnSaveCallback =0;

regards,